# Can't get text box in Word to take up entire page

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to create a text box that takes up the entire page in MS Word and have the text wrap above and below. However, no matter what settings I manipulate, there is always one line of text at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you have your document that you can upload somewhere public for us to see? I'm trying to picture the problem

Comment: Even a screenshot of what you're trying to do (via Imgur) would be a help

Comment: http://adybenisrael.wordpress.com/sample-text-box-problem

Answer (score 1):

*You didn't mention what version of Word you are using. This answer came from Word 2010, but should be applicable to other versions.*

Right click* on the text box and find the "Wrap Text" setting (also available on the Drawing Tools Format tab of the ribbon, in the "Arrange" group). Try experimenting with other settings. I was able to reproduce the problem you described when using the "Square" setting, but changing it to "Tight" resolved it for me.

(*Note: if you right-click on the text box and don't see the Wrap Text option, that means you have inadvertantly selected the text *inside* the textbox. Click on the border of the box and try again.)

Oh, and welcome to SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. I tried changing the Wrap Text to Tight, and now the line jumps to the top of the page!Thanks for the welcome!